# PHP session.save_path failing

Tags: php, redis, memcached, session-storage

I have redis up and running on my Ubuntu 12.04 server on port 9172 (I changed this) and tested for good measure by telnet'ing to it.  I edited my php.ini file to

```
session.save_handler = redis
session.save_path = "tcp://127.0.0.1:9172"
```

and rebooted the machine.  phpinfo now reports the session handler as correctly set to redis.  However, when I attempt to run a simple session setting script

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['time'] = time();
?>
```

I see the error

```
FastCGI-stderr:PHP Warning: Failed to write session data(redis). Please verify that the current   
session.save_path is correct (tcp://127.0.0.1:9172)
```

To be doubly sure that this is a redis issue I tried using memcache as the session handler,

```
session.save_handler=memcache
session.save_path=tcp://127.0.0.1:11211?persistent=1&weight=1&timeout=1&retry_interval=15″
```

and re-ran the session creating script.  No issues and no error.log messages.

Clearly, there is something that is not right when using redis.  I'd be most obliged to anybody who might be able to tell me what the issue could be.

On a side note - I copied the session.save_path for memcache sessions from somewhere.  I haven't been able to find any explanations for the persistent, weight etc bits in the path URL.  Perhaps someone here might be able to explain what they do.

Comment: Are you still facing the issue, or did you solved it? I never faced any such issue.

Comment: I just stopped using redis for the session handler and used memcache instead :-O

Comment: Hmm fair enough. But memcache does not provide persistence. I am not sure if you needed persistence.

Comment: Persistence would be nice but I decided that for now I had to live without it since there are so many other issues to deal with.